# Angular JS 1.x Deployment on IIS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis, angular-material

I am newbie in Angular js, I just finished creating project on Angular js + material.

I ran command `gulp build` and moved all files from dist folder to IIS server directory; it is working fine for the instance but whenever I manually enter an address or refresh it or tries to go back it gives me a 404 error.

I ran through official documentation of Angular but it seems that it is not working at all because these are the errors from Angular 1.x and the official site shows the deployment of only Angular 2 and 4 deployment.

Comment: why deploy on iis? and is it iis express or iis?

Comment: so what are you suggesting where should i deploy it?

Comment: I am a dot net developer by profession the only way I know it, the only way I am doing it :p

Comment: We'd need sample code (routing config, etc). HTML5 mode? IIS logs? Are you calling an API that is returning a 404?

Comment: Provide additional detail.  You may need to set up Url Rewrite, set the base address for the site, or any number of other things.  It's hard to say without more information.

Comment: @Amy I already added URl rewrite but still this 404 occurs and my base url is ```"/"```

Answer (score 0):

If the app in html5Mode and host in IIS as a **Virtual Directory**, it require URL Rewrite for refresh to work:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I already made these changes in my web.config and also downloaded URL rewrite in order to do that, I already gone through the documentation but the thing is that its not working....

Comment: can you show me the config of $locationProvider and $urlRouterProvider in UiRouteConfig, and also, what is the url you try to refresh?

Comment: its only working in Base URL if i enter it can start from base url and navigate by using its anchor tags but when i enter manual URL like `baseurl.com/internal` it gives me 404